# What kind of fungus is this? (I assume it is fungus!)

Tags: fungus

[image: weird fungus found in landscaped beds around office buildings in Redwood Shores near Marine Parkway. What is it? Heavy and roughly size of a softball. I have pictures from other angles but can't figure out how to post more than one...]

weird fungus found in landscaped beds around office buildings in Redwood Shores near Marine Parkway. What is it? Heavy and roughly size of a softball. I have pictures from other angles but can't figure out how to post more than one...

Comment: Post them just like you posted this one as only one angle can't get you the ID you're looking for. As this is the internet, what city, and country are you in?